# How to convert an array of dataFrames into a single data frame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, hive

I have an `array` of data frames called "`dataFrames`" and looks like this:

```
dataFrames(0)
+----------+--------------------+---------+-------------+
|Periodo   |              frutas|freq     |prods_qty    |
+----------+--------------------+---------+-------------+
|         1|Apple, Watermelon   |        1|            2|
|         1|Banana, StrawBerry  |        2|            2|
+----------+--------------------+---------+-------------+

dataFrames(1)
+----------+--------------------+---------+-------------+
|Periodo   |              frutas|freq     |prods_qty    |
+----------+--------------------+---------+-------------+
|         2|Naranjas, Fresas    |        7|            2|
|         2|Pineapple, Apples   |        9|            2|
+----------+--------------------+---------+-------------+
```

Well, I need to get a single `dataframe` like this:

```
+----------+--------------------+---------+-------------+
|Periodo   |              frutas|freq     |prods_qty    |
+----------+--------------------+---------+-------------+
|         1|Apple, Watermelon   |        1|            2|
|         1|Banana, StrawBerry  |        2|            2|
|         2|Naranjas, Fresas    |        7|            2|
|         2|Pineapple, Apples   |        9|            2|
+----------+--------------------+---------+-------------+
```

For this example the length of the array is 1, but the array could any size.

It is possible to achive this... or i need to store the dataframes into a hive table?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `df0.unionAll(df1)` that should be it

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, but as i was telling you... the array could have many time of periods, not just two.

Comment: what do you mean by many time of periods . If you can explains a little bit

Comment: DataFrames could have size of tree, in that case i need to convert: dataFrames(0) + dataFrames(1) + dataFrames(2) into a single DataFrame.  Or could have size of 20... That makes sense?

Comment: so what you are saying is that you can have 20 dataframes like that and you want to merge them into one on one go. is that correct?

Comment: Exactly... Could be 20, 10, 2... it's a dinamyc size.

Comment: "I have an array of DataFrames"... WHY??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `reduce` a sequence or array of DataFrames together using `unionAll`:

```
val dfs = Array(df1, df2, df3)

val all = dfs.reduce(_ unionAll _)
```